# Better way to get tree representation of directory using F#?

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I am new(ish) to F# and am trying to get a tree representation of a filesystem directory. Here's what I came up with:

```
type FSEntry =
  | File of name:string
  | Directory of name:string * entries:seq<FSEntry>

let BuildFSDirectoryTreeNonTailRecursive path = 
  let rec GetEntries (directoryInfo:System.IO.DirectoryInfo) =
    directoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    |> Seq.map (fun info -> 
        match info with 
        | :? System.IO.FileInfo as file -> File (file.Name)
        | :? System.IO.DirectoryInfo as dir -> Directory (dir.Name, GetEntries dir)
        | _ -> failwith "Illegal FileSystemInfo type"
        )

  let directoryInfo = System.IO.DirectoryInfo path
  Directory (path, GetEntries directoryInfo)
```

But... pretty sure that isn't tail recursive. I took a look at the generated IL and didn't see any tail prefix. Is there a better way to do this? I tried using an accumulator but didn't see how that helps. I tried mutual recursive functions and got nowhere. Maybe a continuation would work but I found that confusing.

(I know that stack-depth won't be an issue *in this particular case* but still would like to know how to tackle this non-tail recursion problem in general)

OTOH, it does seem to work. The following prints out what I am expecting:

```
let PrintFSEntry fsEntry =
  let rec printFSEntryHelper indent entry  =
      match entry with
      | File name -> printfn "%s%s" indent name
      | Directory(name, entries) ->
        printfn "%s\\%s" indent name
        entries 
        |> Seq.sortBy (function | File name -> 0 | Directory (name, entries) -> 1)
        |> Seq.iter (printFSEntryHelper (indent + "  "))

  printFSEntryHelper "" fsEntry
```

This should probably be a different question but... how does one go about testing BuildFSDirectoryTreeNonTailRecursive? I suppose I could create an interface and mock it like I would in C#, but I thought F# had better approaches.

**Edited**: Based on the initial comments, I specified that I know stack space probably isn't an issue. I also specify I'm mainly concerned with testing the first function.

Comment: FWIW, if your directory tree is so deep as go overflow the stack without tail recursion, I'd be quite impressed. Also, using a lazy sequence to represent this is a bad idea - use a list or array instead.

Comment: You would typically use continuations to have a tail recursive code that handles trees, but is it a legitimate concern here? The depth of recursion is clearly limited for any practical application. And with path length limit, I doubt there are even theoretical cases where a non-tail recursion wouldn't be enough.

Comment: @ildjarn Okay, I knew that. But since I am just learning F#, I was wondering what might happen if stack depth wasn't an issue. So I would like to know what the proper approach is in that case.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment from earlier - unless you anticipate working with inputs that would cause a stack overflow without tail recursion, there's nothing to be gained from making a function tail-recursive. For your case, the limiting factor is the ~260 characters in path name, beyond which most Windows APIs will start to break. You'll hit that way before you start running out of stack space due to non-tail recursion.

As for testing, you want your functions to be as close to a pure function as possible. This involves refactoring out the pieces of the function that are side-effecting. This is the case with both of your functions - one of them implicitly depends on the filesystem, the other prints text directly to the standard output.

I guess the refactoring I suggest is fairly close to Mark Seemann's points: few mocks - checked, few interfaces - checked, function composition - checked. The example you have however doesn't lend itself nicely to it, because it's an extremely thin veneer over `EnumerateFileSystemInfo`. I can get rid of System.IO like this:

```
type FSInfo = DirInfo of string * string | FileInfo of string

let build enumerate path = 
    let rec entries path = 
        enumerate path
        |> Seq.map (fun info ->
           match info with
           | DirInfo (name, path) ->  Directory(name, entries path)
           | FileInfo name -> File name)

    Directory(path, entries path)
```

And now I'm left with an `enumerate: string -> seq<FSInfo>` function that can easily be replaced with a test implementation that doesn't even touch the drive. Then the default implementation of enumerate would be:

```
let enumerateFileSystem path = 
    let directoryInfo = DirectoryInfo(path)
    directoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    |> Seq.map (fun info -> 
        match info with 
        | :? System.IO.FileInfo as file -> FileInfo (file.Name)
        | :? System.IO.DirectoryInfo as dir -> DirInfo (dir.Name, dir.FullName)
        | _ -> failwith "Illegal FileSystemInfo type")
```

You can see that it has virtually the same shape as the `build` function, minus recursion, since the entire 'core' of your logic is in `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` which lives beyond your code.  This is a slight improvement, not in any way test-induced damage, but still it's not something that will make it onto anyone's slides anytime soon.

Comment: I know that in this particular case stack depth probably isn't an issue. However what I was really asking was how to solve tail recursion problems similar to this in general. I gather from your comment to my question that I should have tried using a continuation. Could you please provide me with an example that uses a continuation :)

Comment: Actually I wasn't really concerned with how to test the print function, that was added just to demonstrate that the tree building seems to work :) As far as your suggestion on how to test the tree building, doesn't that lead to the ["test-induced damage" side of the "Is TDD Dead" debate](http://martinfowler.com/articles/is-tdd-dead/)?

Comment: Martin Seemann in the pdf slides for [Look, no Mocks! Functional TDD with F#"](http://gotocon.com/aarhus-2014/presentations/show_presentation.jsp?oid=6420) (which is unfortunately not itself online), seems to suggest that the power of F# gives one a way to handle testing without using Mocks (or having to completely re-architect your program-under-test). Page 61 says "Functional-first: Few Mocks; Functions: Few interfaces; Function composition: Flexible". I was hoping for F# testing approaches that explored more of this.

Comment: So many questions - a series of blog posts would be more fitting than a SO answer. I've updated my example a bit to make it clearer and less generalized, but that's as far as I'm willing to go here.